# How to obtain duplicate counts accross multiple groups in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am putting together a demographic table(race) from a database. I was able to create a calculated field with if/then else statement but the results only show unique values. For example an individual can select both white and black so I want that individual to be counted twice. meaning I want that individual to be in both white and black category.

I tried creating another calculate field called multiple race=1 if that individual select multiple race but tableau is still counting that person one time

```
If [White]=1   and [Self Neglect]=0   then 'White'
ELSEIf [Black]=1 and [Self Neglect]=0  then 'Black/African American'
ELSEIF [AIAN]=1  and [Self Neglect]=0  then 'American Indian/Alaska Native '
ELSEIF [Other]=1 and [Self Neglect]=0  then 'Other Race'
ELSEIF  [Asian]=1 and [Self Neglect]=0  then 'Asian'
ELSEIF [Native hawaiian]=1 and [Self Neglect]=0  then 'Native Hawaiian/Other Pacific Islander'
Elseif [Self Neglect]=0 then 'Unknown'
```

END

Comment: It might help in this case to post a few rows of dummy data and what your desired output would look like in table form. These questions are a little tricky because there are lots of things to consider data-wise.

Comment: I agree with @DanielSims that we need a visual of what you want the results to look like.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you are trying to count a single row in 2 separate buckets. In order to do you would need to use table calculations. if you can provide a sample data set, we might be able to help better.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Very simple. The answer is to create a calculated field for each individual race group and add them to "Rows" next to each other.